# Creating a zip file of files from repo for revert purposes

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, github

My normal process for deploying to an FTP server from git is this:

- `git status`
- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "Message"`
- `zip update.zip $(git diff --name-only HEAD^)` creates a zip file.
- `git push origin master`

The zip file that is created is a list of all the updated files with their paths.

I'd like to do something similar that creates a zip file with the same content but instead listing the files before they were changed (so the previous commit for each).  This way if there is any issue with any of the files I can quickly revert the changes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of your `zip update.zip $(git diff --name-only HEAD^)` you can use `git archive --format=zip -o update.zip` which won't fail if you have whitespaces in your filenames. This command also take `<tree-ish>` parameter which is tree or commit to produce an archive for.

I do not quite understand what you are trying to achieve, but instead your (quietly complicated) workflow I would think about using something like [`git-ftp`](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp).

Comment: I was intending on having a zip file containing the latest committed files and another zip file containing the previous committed files.  The process I'm using is something I've inherited and wanting to improve on.

Comment: you can limit git archive to only specified paths